# How to use a jQuery data into a PHP code?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to use the value of limit and `offset` into my PHP code but I can't.

Here is my code:

```
var maxData = 0;
var limitt=6;
var offsett=1;

$.ajax({
     url: "../model/conn.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'getData='+'&limit='+limitt+'&offset='+offsett,
                }).done(function( data ) {
                    $("#d1 ").html(data);
                    while (limitt<maxData){
limitt= limitt+6;
offsett=offsett+6;

}
}); 

<?php
if(isset($_POST['getData'])) {
$serv = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$psrd = "";
$db = "nonc";

$conn = mysqli_connect($serv, $user, $psrd, $db);

$limit=$_POST['&limit'];

$offs=$_POST['&offset'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM non_confor limit $offs, $limit;";
$resltt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$checkk = mysqli_num_rows($resltt);
?>
```

When I run my PHP page they show me that I have errors on `$limt` and `$offs`, because they don't receuve the data from AJAX.

Comment: are you  trying to send a post call ?

Comment: the javascript and the Php code are in two separate files, are they?

Comment: yes they are in seperate files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a syntax problem , here is the correction :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../model/conn.php',
    data: { 
        'getData':limit,
        'offset':offsett
    },
    success: function(msg){
       // rest of your code 
    }
});
```

> Data attribute should have as value a json format

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you are using `POST` method for form submission and passing data as a query string which is making an error. Correct that as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../model/conn.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        'getData': 1, // passing 1 as you are using getData in php.
        'offset': offsett,
        'limit': limitt
    },
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#d1 ").html(data);
    while (limitt<maxData){
        limitt= limitt+6;
        offsett=offsett+6;    
    }
});
```

After this, you need to make modification in your PHP code as below:

```
$limit=$_POST['limitt'];
$offs=$_POST['offsett'];
```

After this, your code should work fine. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Great, hope you will upvote and accept my answer :)